# How can I calculate the flow rate of a tcp session?

Tags: session, networking, tcp

In my project I need to calculate the flow rate of a tcp session, should I use total_bytes_of_session/total_time_elapsed or use tcp-windows and tcp-rtt to calculate?

Answer (score 0):

> In my project I need to calculate the flow rate of a tcp session

I assume you mean the flow rate of a session that is just ending and that you have acquired data for?

> should I use total_bytes_of_session/total_time_elapsed

Yes, if you have that data.

> or use tcp-windows and tcp-rtt to calculate?

You don't have that data and you can't get it, so you can't use any calculation that relies on it.

Comment: Oh, sorry for my not-clear description, my project is a net-flow program base on network capture, so I can get the fields of every packet ;-)